# How to declare dependencies inside an amd compatability check without creating 404/mismatched anonymous module during builds?

Tags: javascript, optimization, dependencies, requirejs, r.js

I'm struggling to add a plugin using the following AMD compatability setup to my application:

The snippet from **foo.js** in question:

```
(function (dependencies, module) {
  "use strict";
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    return define(dependencies, module);
  }
  if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    return module(exports);
  }
  window.foo = {};
  module(window.foo, {hex_sha256: hex_sha256});
}(['exports', 'sha256'], function (exports, sha256) {

 // foo

 }));
```

I'm setting **foo** as a dependency in another module called **bar** like so:

```
define(["jquery", "foo", "sha256", "c", "d"], function() {
   // stuff
});
```

And inside the r.js optimizer I define `bar` to be:

```
  {
      name: "bar"
    , include: ["foo", "sha256", "c", "d"]
    , exclude: ["jquery"]
  },
```

This generates the `bar.js` file allright including the abovementioned files.

However when I load my built application, there are still two requests being triggered to `foo.js` and `sha256.js`, which both `404` (optimizer cleans up built files) and who are inside my `bar.js` build layer.

**Question:**
I'm a little lost with the module amd check and am suspecting it being responsible for the unwanted call. Can anyone shed some light on what I should modify in the AMD check to make `foo` callable form inside a build layer?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I tried `shimming` like so:

```
shim: {
  'foo':              { deps: ['sha256'] }
},
```

which takes care of the 404, but returns an:

```
Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (exports, sha256) {....
```

error, so I'm still stuck assuming the hardcoded dependency to `sha256` in my AMD check to be the culprit. Maybe this helps.

**EDIT**:
I'm pretty sure my problems stem from the dependency declaration inside the AMD compatability check.

Comment: Consider using requirejs shim

Comment: When using `shim`, I'm ending up with error `Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (exports, sha256) {...`.

Comment: Are you in control of the source of `foo.js`?

Comment: more or less. I can convert it into a normal module using `define([]...` and this works, but I was wondering if it was possible to correctly use the above syntax and still be able to build in the optimizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two solutions below require modifications to the source of `foo`. Since you can control it, they are both viable:

1. (Quick and dirty) Hardcode the module name in the define call:

   ```
   // foo.js
   if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
       return define("foo", dependencies, module);
   }
   ```
2. (Cleaner) See the code of [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js) at the beginning. I am using it in a project and it seems to compile good with r.js. I tried a simple project setup like yours, and it works; so you have to replace the AMD compatibility code as follows:

   ```
   (function(factory) {
       // Support three module loading scenarios
       if (typeof require === 'function' && typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object') {
           // [1] CommonJS/Node.js
           var target = module['exports'] || exports; // module.exports is for Node.js
           var hex_sha256 = require("sha256");
           factory(target, hex_sha256);
       } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd']) {
           // [2] AMD anonymous module
           define(['exports','sha256'], factory);
       } else {
           // [3] No module loader (plain <script> tag) - put directly in global namespace
           factory(window['foo'] = {}, hex_sha256);
       }
   }(function(exports, sha256){

       // same foo

   }));
   ```

I do not know what magic happens inside r.js and this works...